# How to make gulp-typescript show errors?

Tags: typescript, angular, gulp, gulp-typescript

I am developing an Angular2/Typescript app in VisualStudio and wanted to set up my own ts compiler, but whenever I run it and it finds errors I don't get details about them just this:

```
[16:22:23] Starting 'compile:typescript'...
[16:22:26] TypeScript: 1 semantic error
[16:22:26] TypeScript: emit failed
[16:22:26] Finished 'compile:typescript' after 3.14 s
```

My gulpfile.js is kind of big, but the relevant part is here:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var gutil = require("gulp-util");
var watchifiy = require('watchify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// --------------------------  COMPILE TS ---------------------------
gulp.task('compile:typescript', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src('./Scripts/**/*.ts', { base: './Scripts' })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(
                ts.createProject('Scripts/tsconfig.json'),
                undefined,
                ts.reporter.fullReporter()));

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./Scripts'));
})
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/globals",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Would be thankful for any ideas.

Comment: Does it correctly show errors when run from a nodejs command prompt?  If so check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37971172/40783

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

It looks like this is a known bug, found [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/35160312-fullreporter-not-outputting-correct-source-for-errors).

**Original**

I would suggest using the [`gulp-debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) package, it allows you to `.pipe` into your tasks and capture standard output.

> Debug vinyl file streams to see what files are run through your gulp pipeline

**`gulpfile.js`**

```
var debug = require("gulp-debug");
gulp.task('compile:typescript', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src('./Scripts/**/*.ts', { base: './Scripts' })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(debug()) // here...
        .pipe(ts(
                ts.createProject('Scripts/tsconfig.json'),
                undefined,
                ts.reporter.fullReporter()));

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./Scripts'));
})
```

You'll need to add it to the list of `devDependencies` in your `package.json` so that `npm` will install it.

Comment: Thank for the answer. This shows me what files are processed (all of my .ts files are). How does this lead me closer to finding the semantic error?

Comment: It appears as though you are already using the `fullreporter` which should give you the error messages you're looking for. If not, then it is possible that there are not any additional error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issue. Removing `"noEmit": true,`
 from my tsconfig.json file solved it.

Try removing `"noEmitOnError": true` from yours or set it to false.